# Drawing over GIS data in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want a turtle to colour an area (in-radius 5), on top of the GIS data I have imported.

Please find attached the line of code I am using which is not working.

Is there any way how to do this?

Thanks!

```
extensions[gis]

globals [map-boundary]

to setup
ca
set map-boundary gis:load-dataset "/Users.shp"
create-turtles 50
ask turtles [setxy random-xcor random-ycor set size 1 set color grey]
gis:set-world-envelope (gis:envelope-union-of (gis:envelope-of map-boundary))
gis:import-wms-drawing "https://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service?" "EPSG:4326" "OSM-WMS" 1
reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtle 1 [ask patches in-radius 5 [set pcolor blue]]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean "not working", and lacking the datasets you have I can't reproduce the problem.

The Models Library has some GIS examples.   What's not obvious is where Uri Walenski's "shared-dataset" files are that you need to run them models, but I found some version of them here:
https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.0/models/Code%20Examples/GIS/data/
and when I double-click countries.shp and countries.dbf they download and I can move them to my own new "shared-dataset" folder under the folder my model is in.    That done, the model "create-turtles-inside-polygon" runs.

I removed most of and added a line to draw a blue region around turtle #1 and it seems to work.    What does your attempt to draw the blue region do or not do that's different?

```
extensions [gis]
globals [dataset]
breed [citizens citizen]
citizens-own [cntry_name curr_type]
breed [manual-citizens manual-citizen]
manual-citizens-own [country-name currency-type]

to test-turtles
  clear-all
  set dataset gis:load-dataset "./shared-datasets/countries.shp"
  gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of dataset
  gis:set-drawing-color red
  gis:draw dataset 1

  foreach gis:feature-list-of dataset [ country ->
    gis:create-turtles-inside-polygon country turtles 1
    ;;clear-turtles
  ]
  ask turtle 1 [ ask patches in-radius 5 [set pcolor blue]]
end
```